# What's the utility of the return command in autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

In the instances where the return command returns a value, the utility is obvious. I have seen the `return` command being used even when it is seemingly unnecessary. Let me show the following examples:

Example 1:

```
Loop
{
    if a_index > 25
        break  ; Terminate the loop
    if a_index < 20
        continue ; Skip the below and start a new iteration
    MsgBox, a_index = %a_index% ; This will display only the numbers 20 through 25
}
```

Example 2:

```
IfWinExist, Untitled - Notepad
{
    WinActivate  ; Automatically uses the window found above.   
    return
}
```

Why is the `return` command used in Example 2 but is not used in Example 1? Both examples are copy-pasted/modified-pasted from the autohotkey.com's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`Return` is a control flow command that means "Return the code execution path to the place that called this subroutine, otherwise exit." This way you can build subroutines that are called from multiple places across your script. It is able to return a value when needed, but the primary focus is on returning *control* of what code is executing.

If your Example 2 was followed by

```
IfWinExist, Untitled - Notepad
{
    WinActivate  ; Automatically uses the window found above.   
    return
}
Run Notepade.exe
Return
```

A new instance of notepad before returning to the calling code (e.g. your hotkey).

See more about the [return](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Return.htm) command at [autohotkey.com](http://autohotkey.com).